# Add m2m link in view

Tags: django, django-views

I have model:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name of project', max_length=100, null=False)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

Now I want to add current user in users in CreateView. Like this:

```
class ProjectCreate(CreateView):
    model = Project
    fields = ['name']
    template_name = 'project_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('project_list')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.model.users = self.request.user
        return super(ProjectCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

What I need to write instead `self.model.users = self.request.user`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
self.model.users = self.request.user
```

with

```
form.instance.save()
form.instance.users.add(self.request.user)
```

Comment: I tried to do it, and get the following error : "<Project: Project object>" needs to have a value for field "project" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.

Comment: Remember that `Project` needs to be saved to add a `User` objects.

Comment: I remember it. And a qustion is : I need create Project in form_valid or send the user information to next steps of CreateView?

Comment: If you just want to add the current user, you could just save the form and add the User.